# correct way of storing external programm and making it executable?

Tags: bash, chmod, ln, declare

I downloaded the CLI Client [habash](https://github.com/natfarleydev/habash) for the habit/routine gameification project [habatica.com](https://habatica.com).
In the [fandom wiki for habash](https://habitica.fandom.com/wiki/Habash) it is written that, I need to set environment variables. Additonally I want to make the program habash an ordinary CLI-program, so that I dont have to invoke it via the fullpath.
I describe now, what I have been doing.
I did the following.

- After `declare -x HABITICA_UUID=[myUserID]` I did not find any entries in ~/.bashrc. Any one knows why?
- Therfore I added HABITICA_UUID and HABITICA_TOKEN at the top of ~/.bashrc (and made a comment for myself)
- `chmod 600 ~/.bashrc` because UUID and TOKEN are regarded as PWs.
- `sudo mv ./habash /opt`
- `sudo ln -s /opt/habash/habash /usr/local/bin`

Is this the best way how to do it? (storing in /opt and linkint to /usr/local/bin ; variables in .bashrc and chmoding it with 600)

Answer (score 2):

> - After `declare -x HABITICA_UUID=[myUserID]` I did not find any entries in ~/.bashrc. Any one knows why?

You need to put it in a config file e.g. `~/.bashrc`. Setting it on command line, only has effect on the current shell.

> - Therfore I added HABITICA_UUID and HABITICA_TOKEN at the top of ~/.bashrc (and made a comment for myself)
> - `chmod 600 ~/.bashrc` because UUID and TOKEN are regarded as PWs.

You could but it in a new custom file, `chmod` this file, and add a line to source this file from `~/.bashrc`

in `~/.bashrc` (better to also add code to check that file is readable)

```
. ~/.my_custom_config
```

> - `sudo mv ./habash /opt`
> - `sudo ln -s /opt/habash/habash /usr/local/bin`

Best not to mix `/opt` and `/usr/local`. They have different structures.

Look in to `stow`. You will then put each app into `/usr/local/stow/app-name`, and use stow to link it into `/usr/local/{bin,lib,share,var,etc}`